# 画像URLから、input fileのvalueにする。

Tags: php

ある画像のURLがあるとして、
example.com/123.png

このUrlの画像を

```
<input type="file" value="">
```

上記のvalueに入れることは可能でしょうか？

詳しい方、ご教示頂けますと、幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

PHPやJavascriptでfileのinputに値をセットすることはできません。

隠し項目にしてパスワードファイル等のパスをデフォルトの指定しておくなど、
ユーザーが気づかないうちに危険なファイルを送信させるという手口があったとか無かったとか。
そんなこんなで、セキュリティ上、プログラムから操作できない様になっています。

ユーザー操作で入れてもらうなら、FileではなくURLを入力してもらって、サーバー側でcurlとか使って別途ダウンロードしましょう。